# Big $O$ estimate of $(n\log n+1)^2+ (\log n +1)(n^2+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Give the Big $O$ estimate of  $(n \log n +1)^2 + (\log n +1)(n^2+1)$

Taking big $O$ of the first function (ignoring constant and exponent), ($n\log n + 1)^2$ we get $O (n \log n)$

Taking big $O$ of the second function (ignoring constants), $(\log n + 1) (n^2+1)$ we get $O (n^2 \log n)$.

Taking the max $(n\log n, n^2\log n) = O (n^2\log n)$ <- answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't really ignore the exponent. Expanding the first part, we get:
$$
(n\log n + 1)^2 = n^2\log^2 n + 2n\log n + 1
$$
The $n^2\log^2 n$ term dominates all other terms, so we conclude that it is $O(n^2\log^2 n)$.

Comment: did you distribute the exponent two to each term and then move the exponent to the front to get that final expression after the equal sign?

Comment: @user983246 Adriano multiplied $n\log n+1$ by itself to get the right hand side. If you want to interpret it the way you said, that's fine, but it doesn't generalize to higher powers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ iff there exists a constant $c$ and $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
f(n) \le c \cdot g(n), \quad \forall n \ge n_{0}.
$$
In order to show a big-O notation complexity, it is good to think that you have to find these $c$ and $n_{0}$.

In our case, let
$$
 f(n) = ( n \log{n} + 1)^{2} + (\log{n} + 1)(n^{2}+1).
$$
We have
\begin{align}
( n \log{n} + 1)^{2}
&= n^{2} \log^{2}{n} + 2 \cdot n \log{n} + 1\\
&\le
n^{2} \log^{2}{n} + 3 \cdot n \log{n} \\
&\le 2 \cdot n^{2} \log^{2}{n}
\end{align}
where the inequalities hold for $n \ge 3$ (assuming the logarithm is base $2$).
(Since the constants do not really matter, it is fine to be a little loose!)

Similarly,
\begin{align}
(\log{n} + 1)(n^{2}+1)
&= n^{2}\log{n} + n^{2} + \log{n} + 1\\
&\le 4 \cdot n^{2}\log{n},
\end{align}
for $n \ge 2$.
Combining the above, we have
\begin{align}
f(n)&=( n \log{n} + 1)^{2} + (\log{n} + 1)(n^{2}+1) \\
&\le 2 \cdot n^{2} \log^{2}{n} + 4 \cdot n^{2}\log{n} \\
&\le 6 \cdot n^{2} \log^{2}{n},
\end{align}
for $n \ge 3$.
By the last inequality, we conclude that
$$
f(n) = O(n^{2} \log^{2}{n}).
$$